# How to synchronize multiple background worker class in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have implemented background worker class something similar to below sample and I want to update my UI each time the background worker is completed.

```
          for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
                worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
                worker.RunWorkerAsync(i);

                while (worker.IsBusy == true)
                {
                   Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
```

the Worker_DoWork return datarow and Worker_RunWorkerCompleted is adding returned result to data grid. but the function never reach in Worker_RunWorkerCompleted in a proper order.  How could I can solve this?

**EDIT:**

To make it clear I am updating with more detail.

```
 <my:DataGrid x:Name="theGrid" RowHeight="30" ItemsSource="{Binding Category}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HeadersVisibility="All" Margin="235,96.5,84,65.5">
            <my:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander>
                        <my:DataGrid Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HeadersVisibility="Column"> </my:DataGrid>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </my:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </my:DataGrid>


    //List of objects
    List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {      
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(i);

            while (worker.IsBusy == true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }

    void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        long i = Convert.ToInt64(e.Argument);
        Category cat = new Category { CategoryID = i, Name = "Category" + i };
        cat.Products = new List<Product>();

        for (long j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            Product p = new Product { ProductID = (i * j), Name = "Product " + (i * j).ToString() };
            cat.Products.Add(p);
        }

        e.Result = cat;
    }

    void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Category cat = ((Category)e.Result);
        Categories.Add(cat);
        theGrid.ItemsSource = Categories;
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public long CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear - is the code you've written running in the UI thread?

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't reach in a proper order"

Comment: I think he means, that the executing first BW and after second, it's not guranteed that the result from first comes before that one second.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes the code is running in the UI thread.

Comment: @MartinMoser in my code the do worker works properly then freeze the code in while loop.

Comment: I don't really understand why you use a background worker to do the job and then you freeze the UI thread with sleep. If you do it this way then don't use a thread just use a simple function call instead and then your results will be in correct order too.

Comment: @BigL I used BW because the the method inside the do worker takes a long time to calculate. so the UI need to update based on that.

Comment: @nikownj: But the UI won't be able to update if you're calling `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread.  You told the `Thread` responsible for upgrading the UI to `Sleep`, so it is not going to be updating the UI.  If you want the UI to be able to update, remove the entire `while` loop.  Of course, you may want to disable some parts of the UI while the task is running (e.g., `Button1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're still blocking the UI thread - it won't get to process events until all your BackgroundWorkers have completed. That goes against the whole *point* of `BackgroundWorker`. You should start them, and just let them finish. If you need to make some other change when they've finished, you should do that in the handler for `RunWorkerCompleted` - possibly keeping count of how many have finished (if you start them in parallel) or starting a new one if you want to run them in series, until you've run all the ones you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

When using background worker the main aim is to avoid blocking/freezing of the UI thread. If the Do_Work method takes a long time then try to have the Progress_Changed event on the background worker and update the progress on the UI from this method. The worker_Completed is only called when the background worker's associated task is complete. You need to raise the Progress Changed event in between from the Do_Work to update the progress.

Some code for associated the Progress changed event:

```
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Worker_ProgressChanged);
```